# How does relativity...work?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, relativity

I understand the principles of relativity. I understand why we need relativity if we are to have the laws of physics be the same in all inertial frames. But physically speaking, how does relativity actually work? In particular, I was thinking about length contradiction, and I don't understand *how* moving objects shrink. I understand why they need to, just not how. Is the fabric of spacetime bending in some weird way around a speeding object in order to shrink the object? (Presumably, this might make sense, since massive objects warp spacetime, and fast moving objects have a large relativistic mass). Is this explainable using general relativity?

Edit: To elaborate, my question is more about the mechanics of what is happening to make the object appear shorter. For example, consider a straw in a glass of water, and a straw not in a glass of water. In both cases, the straw is the same. However, it looks weirdly disjointed when in the glass of water; from a new perspective, it looks different. However, there is a good explanation for why this is; the light refracts when changing mediums, and this thus changes your perception. I'm looking for a similar explanation as to "how" the perception that something has changed length actually comes about in S.R. –

Comment: Magnetism is possible because of relativity... I'm talking about an electromagnet.

Comment: NOTHING shrinks, really.  To fully understand this you need to learn special relativity, and avoid pop science explanations.  No shortcuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object does not physically shrink. Its length appears to change when viewed from a moving reference frame. You must remember that the effects of relativity are symmetrical. If a fast moving spaceship, and all the people in it, seem to have contracted in length from your perspective, from their's it is you who is fast moving and contracted.

The effect comes about in a way that is precisely analogous to a rotation of spatial coordinates. If you have a 3D coordinate system that is rotated relative to mine so that your axes point in different directions to mine. We will now disagree about the coordinates of any point in that space. Moreover, if we consider two points in space, we will disagree about the horizontal and vertical distances between them, for example. The same effect occurs in spacetime. Observers that are stationary relative to each other each have a time axis pointing in a common direction, but if they start to move their time axes diverge so they are no longer pointing in the same direction in 4D space, which causes them to disagree about positions and separations in time.

Comment: My question is more about the mechanics of what is happening to make the object appear shorter. For example, consider a straw in a glass of water, and a straw not in a glass of water. In both cases, the straw is the same. However, it looks weirdly disjointed when in the glass of water; from a new perspective, it looks different. However, there is a good explanation for why this is; the light refracts when changing mediums, and this thus changes your perception. I'm looking for a similar explanation as to "how" the perception that something has changed length actually comes about in S.R.

Comment: @MarcelMazur First think about how one measures the length of something that is moving relative to them. Then think about how your measurement would appear to someone who is at rest relative to the object whose length you are measuring.

Comment: I disagree that the object doesn't physically shrink. Consider the Ladder Paradox, where it's possible to close both the front and back doors of a 10-foot deep barn as a person carrying a 20-foot ladder runs through it (at near-light speed). The ladder doesn't just *look* shorter from the barn's frame, it actually *is* shorter (you can close both doors). Of course, from the ladder's perspective, the barn has shrunk, so there is no absolute definition of what's shrinking. But in neither case does the barn or ladder only *appear* shorter, it is actually, *in reality*, shorter than when at rest.

Comment: That isn't quite right- you are shutting the doors simultaneously in your reference frame, but in the ladder's frame the exit door re-opens before the entry door closes, so the leading end of the ladder has already left the barn. Obviously the shrinking can't be real- think of it this way, if the ladder is observed by three observers each moving at different speeds they each think it is shrunk by a different amount- it cannot actually shrink by three different amounts simultaneously.

Comment: @NuclearWang Seems like a bit of a philosophical problem. What is reality? If every test that I perform in my frame suggests that the the ladder has shrunken, then perhaps in my reality it has actually shrunken. But I think this is why the notion of proper length is needed; this gives a length that everyone can agree upon, that is, the length in the rest frame of the object.

Comment: @AaronStevens To measure something, you need to measure the positions of the ends of the thing at the same time. If you are outside a spaceship measuring the spaceship, a person in the spaceship will see you measure the front end before the back end, so they will think you think the spaceship is shorter than what they think. So what you're saying is that this (length contraction) is really a direct consequence of time dilation, and simultaneity? (The question then, I suppose, is how does time dilation actually occur, but perhaps this is meta physics)

Comment: @NuclearWang Been thinking about this some more, and I think that you must be right in saying that the length contraction happens in reality. If this weren't the case, and thinks didn't actually shrink, in E&M there would be no basis for the magnetic force. After all, what we consider to be a magnetic force is really, in a moving particle's frame, an electric force (as explained by Grithis in chapter 12 of his E&M book) due to length contraction in the moving frame. It is not just that the frame sees things contracted: they actually are contracted, for all purpose of the frames reality !

Comment: @MarcoOcram thoughts? ^^

Comment: We might be talking at cross purposes. Nothing physically shrinks. From the perspective of a comet, the entire world is moving and will be somewhat length-contracted. We do not shrink as a consequence. That said, length contraction is a real phenomenon. Imagine when you tilt a wide object to get it through a narrow doorway. The object does not shrink, but its rotation causes it to present a narrower form to the doorway. Consider the effect as being analogous to that.

Comment: Lorentz invariance is not real? Einstein is wrong? This is nonsense, it is not a matter of opinion. In what the ""apperaence?" if i measure with a ruler a length, it appears as a numeral, because it is the length i have measured. Information which cannot be gained otherwise about elemamtery particles, uses time dilation, so data is then possible to exctract. t

Answer (score 1):

It shrinks for simultaneous (according to your own clock) readings of a your meter stick at both ends. Given that the object is in a different frame, the measurement cannot be simultaneous to it's clock, and will furthermore be of a not contracted length. So you have a "shorter" time displacement and you should have as a consequence a shorter spatial displacement, because the overall space-time difference must be agreed between you and the thing.

So, simultanous in our frame means $$\Delta t = 0$$. But $$-c^2\Delta t^2+\Delta x^2 = \Delta x^2 = -c^2\Delta t'^2+\Delta x'^2$$. So it must be that

$$\Delta x'^2 > \Delta x^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you're in Chicago, facing New York, which is 800 miles straight ahead.

Now turn ninety degrees to the right.  All of a sudden, New York is 800 miles to your left!

How did New York manage to shift its position so dramatically all of a sudden?

The answer, of course, is that it didn't.  What changed is your **description** of New York's location, which switched from one perfectly valid description ("800 miles straight ahead when I face east") to another ("800 miles to my left when I face south").

That's just what happens in relativity.  There is no one correct answer to "how long is the meter stick?" any more than there's one correct answer to "which direction is New York?".  The direction of New York depends on which way you're facing.  The length of the meter stick depends on how fast you're traveling with respect to that stick.  Neither New York nor the stick needs to know anything about this, or to adjust itself in any way just because you changed from one description to another.

Comment: I understand this. As another example, you could consider a straw in a glass of water, and a straw not in a glass of water. Your description of the straw is different in the two cases, but the straw itself is the same physically. However, there is a physical explanation for what is going on here; in the case of straw in glass, the light refracts as it moves between mediums, changing your view of it. I am looking for some sort of analogous explanation for relativistic effects.

Comment: Yes. Before i even started to prove modern physics does not exist, i attempted to understand it. After that i wrote that Einstein is wrong iff mine is right. I xid not publish because i'm not stupid. Read Einstein's paper, some things are implicit ,others are mot even there, and there are real issues, question marks. The system you use is big. As if you were reffering to global properties. These can be sepetated arbitrarily far enough to deny any strictly defined measurement. This is where you realize it is local. All measurements are made precily here at the origin, or exteremly close to it

Answer (score 0):

There was an experiment attempting to verify something stupid, for that there is no way the speed of light is absolute and constant, because it is difficult comprehend, and contradicts it being dependant on the media.

There is no contradiction, and denial of the constancy can be made, but this is just more math to the same destination.

The experiment failed, and the counter intitive notions became empirical facts.

Einstein did not know of this experiments for his theory.

But it seems empirical facts are the only way. If light behaves like was seen in the experiment, its only a matter of simple math to show it is indeed so. Is it real? Experiments agree with yes

Answer (score -6):

It's just a math model, it's not necessarily literally describing reality. You can interprete it that way in some instances if you want to. I don't think that any of the special relativity effects have been observed directly and explicitly..

Comment: "I don't think that any of the special relativity effects have been observed directly and explicitly.." - Muons literally live longer when they go faster. That's why we're able to see them on the ground when they're produced at the top of the atmosphere. This is a direct and explicit observation of time dilation.

Comment: Saying "I don't think" isn't a great way to answer a question, especially when you are wrong.  Did you even try to look it up?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_special_relativity

Comment: Full ACK on the previous comments: Special Relativity is one of the best tested theories, and every test to date has only yielded the result that its predictions are both measurable and correct. Similar story with General Relativity (though we don't have as much opportunity to test this as in the Special Relativity case) and Quantum Mechanics (the weirdest and probably most well-tested of the three, it's just so easy and cool to do). This site is driven by people who know this, so no answer denying this will be well received around here.

Comment: Are all of you crazy? Show me when was lenght contraction ever shown explicitly, do you know what that word means? From muons perspective they live exactly as long as regardless of speed, and have any of you geniuses gone close to c to see what is actually happening with lenght. No. SR and GR are just math models that apply to a very specific set of systems.

Comment: Also even if the theory was 100 percent right the objects would never shrink but rotate instead. Obviously people answering this question never attended a single university physics class..

Comment: @LeoKovacic The user with the top accepted answer claims to actually hold a PhD in quantum theory, so presumably they would have attended at least one university physics class.

Comment: I claim to be Jackie Chan , does it really matter if it's true right now? No. Bottom line is all I said is correct and other responses are not in the sense that they have at least misinterpreted applied math..

Comment: @LeoKovacic It isn't just "applied math".  It is the _physical_ model which most accurately describes what is taking place.  What you said is _not correct_.  The reason relativity is so well known is exactly because it is describing reality, better than any previous models.  This is how science works.

Comment: It's precisely what I said it is

Comment: It's just a model, as is QM. There are many interpretations of these models, it's not known for sure whether things really literally behave like that or not. and fundamentally there is no difference between math and physics anyway it's just that some math tends to model reality on some scales, and some "physics" even produces easier ways to calculate things mathematicians couldnt do based only on "math". The very foundation of modern science is non dual in this sense(newton's  principia ) who are you to say otherwise

Comment: And the op asked how would the objects appear. The right answer is basically they would appear rotated. Not whet they said.

Comment: @JMac And the op asked how would the objects appear. The right answer is basically they would appear rotated. Not whet they said.